# How to regularly send file from Windows to Linux server

Tags: linux, windows, ftp, ftps

I have a simple question. I want my Windows 7 PC to send a file to Linux server every minute. This would be easy to do on Linux via cronjobs but I have really no idea how to do that on Windows.

For example. We have a file called `example.txt` in `c:/programfiles/folder/` on my Windows PC.

I want to send that file to Linux server to folder `/home/fold`.

Any idea what to use and how? Does Windows have anything similar to
cronjob? What to use instead of scp? Maybe use FTP but my Linux server
only works with explicit TLS and I have no idea how to force `ftp`
client to send that file in Windows.

Ty in advance and sorry if I ask stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

Windows equivalent to the cron is [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler).

The Windows `ftp.exe` client does not support TLS/SSL. It also does not support a passive FTP mode. So you have to use a different client. Once you have to use a different client anyway, you can use SFTP.

So take any scriptable SFTP client (or FTPS or SCP client if your prefer) and schedule it to be run using Windows Scheduler.

---

For example with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/), you can use a batch-file like:

```
@echo off

winscp.com /log=winscp.log /command ^
    "open sftp://user:password@example.com/" ^
    "put c:\path\file.txt /path/" ^
    "exit"
```

(WinSCP supports FTPS and SCP too).

Then, in Windows control panel go to *System and Security > Administrative Tools > Schedule Tasks* and add a new task.

For details see my guide for [scheduling file transfers to FTP/SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*