# How can I schedule the transfer of a CSV file resulting from a Snowflake query to an FTP server?

Tags: ftp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to transfer a file from Snowflake to the FTP.
I have the address of the FTP, the username and password

I can create a stage and put the data in the stage. But I don't know how to send the data from the stage to the FTP server

I know how to do it for S3, but not to an FTP server.

Docs, youtube, forums, I can't seem to find an answer

Can you help please? Thank you!

Comment: When you are saying FTP server, do you mean that you must use FTP for transferring the files from Snowflake to this server? If it is FTP only for your users then you can install SnowSQL on that server and get files directly from Snowflake

Comment: There might be native way in "Snowflake". But for standalone automated upload, see [How to regularly send file from Windows to Linux server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31965825/850848).

Comment: There is no direct native way without using an application in between, like SnowSQL on the FTP server or one of the connectors.

Comment: You could also stop using FTP to deliver data to other sources and instead share the data directly from Snowflake.  Setup reader accounts for other companies to get the data themselves directly from Snowflake.  Just a thought...